# ReactJS: Unexpected token error from static proptypes

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

I am getting error with

```
static propTypes = {}
```

The error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:21) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Here is my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-arrow-functions", "transform-class-properties"]
}
```

I have tried changing `es2015` to `es2016`, and adding `stage-0`/`stage-2`. I have also tried doing `MyClass.propTypes` but neither worked.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using webpack? Can you please share your webpack.config.js file?

Answer (score 3):

Some time has passed and some things have changed. Here's what's working for me:

```
// .eslintrc
{
    "plugins": ["babel"],
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
}

// .babelrc
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

And we need the following dependencies:

With Yarn:

```
$ yarn add @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
$ yarn add eslint babel-eslint eslint-plugin-babel eslint-plugin-react
```

With NPM:

```
$ npm i --save @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
$ npm i --save eslint babel-eslint eslint-plugin-babel eslint-plugin-react
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I had a typo in my file name... wrote file.js instead of file.jsx.

Answer (score 1):

**Step : 1 -** I am assuming you are installing [prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) `npm install --save prop-types` as a seperate library and then importing it in the project

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

And then making use of it inside your project .

**Step: 2** - One of the ways is to make use of `babel-polyfill` , You can install it as a project dependency `npm install --save babel-polyfill` and inside your `webpack.config.js` you can pass it to the entry point (You can amend this accordingly):

```
entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./App.jsx"],
```

You can read more about babel Polyfill [Here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/)

And if you are using `eslint` you can add `"parser": "babel-eslint"` to the 
`.eslintrc` file

```
{ "parser": "babel-eslint" }
```

You can read more about eslint config [Here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)